# Key and lock, which one is made first?

Tags: instrument

I know my is question is off-topic, but I can not find a suitable SE site for this question. Forgive me.

I'm just curious about the order of producing a key and its lock, and the reason or procedure for it.

Comment: ask a locksmith!

Comment: Won't making a key first, and an appropriate lock later on, be silly?

Comment: @julianfernandez: How many locksmiths do you know?

Comment: I should imagine they are built in whichever order is cheaper for the manufacturer. The manufacturer has full specifications with tolerances for each lock combination, both the key and lock are described by these. There is no reason that they can't be made separately. I should expect, though, that a reasonable production setup would be a pin loading jig, where the line worker fills the pin cylinder for the next lock, whilst in parallel a small CNC grinder makes the key for that particular lock (perhaps both processes are robotic). The worker then tests the key, and packages lock and key.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about locksmithing.

Comment: I'll be honest, this strikes me as an interesting question. However, it's funny to me that the question basically says, "I know this is off-topic, but it's off-topic everywhere, so it may as well be off-topic here"...